# How to substitute variable in file path

Tags: r

I know nothing about R, but would like to know to substitute a variable that could be used to replace the `/home/subdirectory/DataFiles/` in the following (snippet) of R code:

```
x1 <- subset(read.csv("/home/subdirectory/DataFiles/Isic_bilateral_trade1.csv"),
             year>=1990)
```

Comment: `paste` is your friend.  `path <- '/home/...'; read.csv(paste(path, filename, sep='/'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the directory as a variable and use the file.path method:

```
dataDir <- "/home/subdirectory/DataFiles"
x1 <- subset(read.csv(file.path(dataDir, "Isic_bilateral_trade1.csv")),year>=1990)
```

etc.